# Is it 1089-able?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, integer

\$ 1089 \$ is a very special number. To prove why, select any 3-digit number whose first and last digits differ by at least 2. Then, reverse the digits, and take the *difference* of these two numbers. Reverse the digits once more, and *add* these two numbers together. You will get \$ 1089 \$. The magic is left as an exercise to the reader.

Taking this a step further, let's define an algorithm for all possible integers:

- Choose any positive integer \$ n \$
- Reverse the digits of \$ n \$, and call it \$ x \$
- Set \$ n \$ equal to \$ n - x \$ if \$ x < n \$, and \$ n + x \$ otherwise
- Repeat the above step until \$ n \$ reaches a number it has already visited

In turns out that this algorithm gets stuck in an infinite loop, for certain numbers. Let's call a number *1089-able™*, if it does in fact terminate (in other words, a duplicate is reached at some point). For example, everyone's favorite number, `2022`, is *1089-able™*:

```
2022 + 2202 ->
4224 + 4224 ->
8448 + 8448 ->
16896 + 69861 ->
86757 - 75768 ->
10989 + 98901 ->
109890 - 98901 ->
10989 (*)
```

In this challenge, you are given a positive integer, and are required to determine whether it is *1089-able™*. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution in bytes wins.

The first 50 *non-1089-able™* numbers are as follows:

```
[10057, 10118, 10168, 10254, 10458, 10598, 10698, 10798, 10898, 11047, 11108, 11158, 11244, 11448, 11499, 11588, 11688, 11788, 11888, 11998, 11999, 12037, 12148, 12234, 12438, 12489, 12578, 12678, 12778, 12878, 12988, 12989, 13027, 13138, 13224, 13428, 13479, 13568, 13668, 13768, 13868, 13978, 13979, 14017, 14128, 14198, 14214, 14418, 14469, 14558]
```

Comment: Is it a valid format to have a max recursion depth error when it's not 1089-able?

Comment: @Steffan I'd say no, because if your recursion depth is infinite, it would run forever. On the other hand, if it were finite, even a 1089-able number can encounter such an error.

Comment: @Steffan https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24411/using-resource-exhaustion-with-a-semi-deciding-algorithm

Comment: Is it actually a decidable problem? Unless one studies the problem, there is no guarantee that a given solution is correct for *all* numbers, and not just the tested ones.

Comment: @MatteoC. I'm not sure, but I think it's ok to post an answer that doesn't necessarily work outside the known test cases. Correct until proven wrong, if you will. That being said, I'd be interested to see an answer accompanied by a provably-correct explanation. I may award a bounty for such a solution, if anyone is willing to take up the challenge.

Comment: I was sure this was gonna be a question about tax forms.

Comment: I've checked all integers up to (but not including, because I'm 0-indexed) one billion, and the interesting numbers are all of the form `^(109*890*)+$`.

Comment: Of those numbers, the ones of the form `^109*8900+$` never loop except for the three exceptions `108900`, `1098900` and `10989000`, which you can avoid by checking for `^1099+8900+$` which you will hit eventually if you don't loop.

Comment: @Neil a billion - 10 (13?) decimals - isn't all that much. For example, `109998900000000109998900000000109998900000000` found by educated guessing also does not loop.

Comment: @loopywalt I checked all integers of up to 9 digits, and found which patterns were interesting, and then I checked larger integers, but as I mentioned, only those using a simpler pattern, so yes, I have left the question of other integers matching my original pattern, which includes your example, unanswered.

Comment: @Neil just saying that guessing "the" pattern from brute forcing the first so-and-so many numbers probably won't work.

Comment: @loopywalt Sure, but it beats the other people who just tested the 50 provided exceptions.

Comment: Suggested test case: non 1089-able: `109999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999009999999999900999999999998900000000000000000000000000000000000000000010890000001099999999890000000010999999900999999999999999999999999999999999999999999989000000000010890000000001089000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` this  adds two trailing zeros and two nines in the first group of nines every eight steps. Everything else stays the same. (Most likely not a minimal example).

Answer (score 7):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 117 bytes

```
def f(n):
    v={n}
    while 1:
        x=int(str(n)[::-1]);n-=[-x,x][x<n]
        if n in v:return 1
        if n/100in v:return 0
        v|={n}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TZJNTsMwEEbFsjmF2TmiERl7HDuBnCTKohIJjQQuStMSBJyETVnAneA0eMZBajZP3-jN-C8f308v03bnT6evw9Rn7udw1_Wilz6tktWxfvXvyep5Ozx0AkJhNdeDn-R-GoPQVFUGbXrjs7rJ5vXcNvOtb4M09MKLwYtjNXbTYfQCluI15Pl5PQ_14xstEhf_vfj0O183QTN2LSAHcIyCoQwS0HAyJaOIsBGOERxqD-QE3AAKqR0QOWFZEozjVETYCBdRlgvIVLmmmQq4XSlNwxRqTuhYMZZTEWEjXETpFpCpc0XDNHC7VoqGaVSc0LJi-NC6iLARLqK0C8jEHGgYArcj8K4xbJSAfIOIBZvGuDZJ-t0oZnqgcePvOwnrx80sw8WnVxBeXYRvs9934yRkL-dUXNZCsk5KGl_q_3f5Aw)

It works for all positive integers less or equal to the 50th *non-1089-able™* number.

Haven't proven that it works for numbers greater than `14558`.

Comment: use a recursive lambda for [88 bytes](https://tio.run/##TZHBbsMgEETv/QqOJnFUFhYDltwfsawqVUODlOII@5KvT9klh54eI82MgLk/9uuajb@X5zNOt/Pv1/dZ5H6b5mVUKYr8DkqlLDZxuW0XkQWf1yJil49dGaeU927bS5flPI4nWKQ86UM5dPmjyH47znmRz5jKtn/GFPeHmMRcG63rBSgAzxgY2iIBLSsbGEODa/CM6qF4JSvgAGikOCCywhAI1rMaGlyDbwjhBXJqZahTA8e1NlSm0bBCzxbrWA0NrsE3BP8COY3SVGaA40ZrKjOoWaFji@VHm6HBNfiG4F4gJyqgMgSOI/CtsV6UgPyDiAM7rfXL273QJP@@fJrmJGKdLNF45Zx/Lh305A5S0MTrXtdM/bzIutUf)

Comment: [87 bytes](https://tinyurl.com/2p82npcv) based on @friddo's version by changing the `if else` (and with `n-[-(x:=int(str(n)[::-1])),x][x<n]` instead of `n+(r:=int(str(n)[::-1]))-2*r*(n>r)` to more closely resemble your original answer - although both are the same byte-count, so not too important).

Comment: [79 bytes](https://tio.run/##TdHBboUgEAXQfb@CpTS@1IFBwJT@iDGNTUsfSYtGXfi@3jqDi65ObrwzQZgf233K2s3LccTwM/5@fI4i189rl0XKYhXTUuUXaBoK8hVCiFW@9XsXUt6qdTu/yr7rbjDI@rYP/f4W8nCO11keMS3r9h5T3B4iiP5cYmwtoAFwTMsogwQaTsYzbcEWHHN2aPyUE/AAKKRxQOSE3hPGcWoLtuAK3l9QUzWadirgcaU0LVOoOaHjirGc2oItuIJ3F9TUjaJlGnhcK0XLNCpOaLli@Kd1W7AFV/D2gprYAC1D4HEEPjWeByWQbxCx5aYxbniaF3qQf1ceQp9EnBaR6CGXMX9/VVBT20uRosjTJmKV6n6Qgzz@AA) based on @KevinCruijssen's version.

Comment: -1 byte from @ovs': [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TdHBboUgEAXQfb@CpbS@1IFBwDy@xJjGpqUladGoC9/XW2dw0dXJjXcmCPNj@56ydvNyHDH8jL/vH6PI9fPaZZGyWMW0VPkVmoaCvEMIscov/d6FlLdq3c6vsu@6Gwyyvu1Dv9/zcE7XWR4xLev2FlPcHiKI/txhbC2gAXBMyyiDBBpOxjNtwRYcc3Zo/JQT8AAopHFA5ITeE8Zxagu24AreX1BTNZp2KuBxpTQtU6g5oeOKsZzagi24gncX1NSNomUaeFwrRcs0Kk5ouWL4p3VbsAVX8PaCmtgALUPgcQQ@NZ4HJZBvELHlpjFueJoXeo9/Vx5Cn0ScFpHoHZcxf31WUFPbS5GiyNMmYpXqfpCDPP4A "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>162</s> <s>136</s> 128 bytes

```
def h(n,e=0):e=(e or[])+[n];n+=(x:=int(str(n)[::-1]),-x)[x<n];return f"1089{(len(z:=str(n))-7)*'9'}099"!=z and(n in e or h(n,e))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TZLRSsMwFIbx1qeIu1niWkjSkyap5klKkYGtK0g2ug62ieB7eLMbxVfSp7HnpIJXHz_8_5-TnLx_7k7jZhsvl4_D2OXu--2x7diGx6wNUlRt4C3bDnUjVnVs7uIq8GMV-jjy_TjwKOqqylUjsvwo6uP95Bja8TBE1i2UdP6FP7eRn6uQzCK34nbpl6_S-8VNOLN1fOSR9ZHhGelQIdIcP1dfXT_sx4eu78YTC6xWUhqbMSWVcoSSoA0gwJAynlAm2ARHmDwYn0hKUUBpwLgCIAXeI4wjVSbYBJfg_Qx0allgp1YU17rAMg0FKXBkMZZUmWATXIJ3M9BZSI1lhaJ4oTWWFaBJgSWLoUsXZYJNcAnezkAnSIVloCgOiqaGaVAE0AsClOQ0xjXXuwGX-u_JQ6h71k1r6XFBwzo-tVxl6PaC9R2L23HaWC-aeWF_H-gX)

Haven't proven that it works for *non-1089-able™* numbers past the first 50.

-26 bytes thanks to benrg and ovs (and for pointing out the rules with reusable functions)

-8 bytes thanks to Jo King

Comment: `n+=(x:=int(str(n)[::-1]),-x)[x<n]` is a bit shorter. I think the last three lines can be just `return f"1089{(len(z:=str(n))-7)*'9'}099"!=z and(n in e or h(n,e))` (no need to test the length of `z`, it'll compare unequal anyway)

Comment: Functions [have to be reusable](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4939/64121), and requiring an additional input is not allowed. But this can be fixed without costing bytes: `def h(n,*e):`, `e+=n,` and `return h(n,*e)` save two bytes even.

Comment: the first statement can be replaced with `e=(e or[])+[n]`

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 70 bytes

```
^
$($^$%')*_;$%'*_¶
^(_+);\1\B|;

_+
$.&
D^`
/^./}s`^1099+8900+¶.+

^¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvqqHhnvA/jktFQyVORVVdUyveGkhpxR/axhWnEa@taR1jGONUY83FFa/NpaKnxuUSl8ClH6enX1ucEGdoYGmpbWFpYKB9aJueNhdX3KFt//8bGRgZcRkaGJiaAwA) Link only includes two test cases as it's too slow otherwise. Explanation:

```
^
$($^$%')*_;$%'*_¶
```

Take the first number and its reverse and convert them both to unary with the reversed number first.

```
^(_+);\1\B|;
```

Subtract the two numbers of the second is larger otherwise add them.

```
_+
$.&
```

Convert back to decimal.

```
D^`
```

Delete the total if it's been seen before.

```
s`^1099+8900+¶.+
```

But delete the entire buffer if the value will increase infinitely.

```
/^./}`
```

Repeat until at least the current total was deleted.

```
^¶
```

Check to see whether an infinite loop was detected.

Comment: I've verified that the algorithm is valid up to a billion, although since Retina calculates via string manipulation you'll probably find that it can't actually deal with values that high in practice.

Answer (score 3):

### [Javascript](https://www.javascript.com/), <strike>149</strike> <strike>145</strike> <strike>137</strike> 128 bytes

```javascript
c=n=>{a=[n];while(n){x=+[...''+n].reverse().join``;n=x<n?n-x:n+x;if(a[i='includes'](n))return 1;if(a[i](n/100))break;a.push(n)}}
```

- Thanks to [@Radvylf Programs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/79857/radvylf-programs) for saving 4 bytes!
- Saved 8 bytes replacing `return false` with `break` now that the loop is wrapped
- Thanks to [@Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan) for saving 9 bytes!

[Try me online.](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NZLBToQwFEXjUr6CzAYaHKTlFYoMuvMnCMkg05lBSTEwoySTSfwPNy507-_o19i-4urklntvHn19_1T9Rn58fB0P26X4eWsKVdye6qJUVf66bzvpK3KaiqAMw9DzAlWFg3yRwyh9Ej72rVqvc1VMK3WnltONCqa83fp12RZeq5ruuJGjV-kGMsjDcVAunT_rs2saRYQ8DLJ-yuvw-Tjute98tnP8XnyrXhWl9vD0yqURpQKRIBgHA-CoeIZILFILgdAeE9dERTFAGZg4BUAFWWbABarEIrUQFlk2wzhZFJtORjHOWGzKGMSoQKCFp6gSi9RCWGRihnHGETNlMcV4zJgpi4GhghQtHH86TixSC2GRpTOMEyJqyoBiHChODXpQA8AbBEjQybmoHGfbD34nD27rFm6Ua6xcfe1hJ9XusNc6CMjJudQra3x9rtdGiNv0auw7GXb9zl_c1_qFbBYkd-bF_T-kPw)

### [Javascript](https://www.javascript.com/), 171 bytes (readable)

```javascript
c=n=>{
    a = [n]
    while(n){
        x=+n.toString().split('').reverse().join('')
        n=x<n?n-x:n+x
        if(a.includes(n)) return true
        if(a.includes(n/100)) break
        a.push(n)
    }
}
```

[Try me online.](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZI9TsNAEIVFGZ_CShNbAeNdz9prwNBxAcoohUk2icEaR_6BSFFOQpMCKhquA6dhdjZUuPn0Zt8bjXfn7R2bpTkeP4Z-daG_PxcFFrd7z6ev9At_hnNv9LqpahNguPdGo10xxahvHvq2wnUQRt22rvpgMgmj1ryYtjNUe2oqtCWyY7G7wTu82F3hdEe6WgVlVOGiHpamo5ah35p-aNHv28H8P78UcUyex9aUz3RaRtuh21DMGx28gxv55-wLGyxm5FTZuS9iITQjZUgFFqBYqZyROmQOmkEeGyeyEhwQEmxcALCCPLdQmlXqkDlohzw_wTplnNieUnBcysQ2k5CwAs0WlbFKHTIH7ZDrE6wziaVtlgiOJ1LaZglIVpCxRfFPJ6lD5qAd8uwE64RY2GYgOA6CpwYa1AL4BgFSdiql5563atqgNr1f0VLE14Qbn649qg2u-w3p6dSuBz3fIqD6rJrTsy0a7JraRHWzDsb3JS3Rchxe_z3c3879Ag)

A good chunk of the bytes in this are coming from included functions `.reverse()`, `.includes()`, etc. Have not tested past the 50 provided.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! You can save a few bytes with `.split\`\`` and `.join\`\``, which abuse [tagged template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates).

Comment: also, `(''+n).split\`\`` can be `[...''+n]`

Comment: also, instead of the first `a.includes`, you can do `a[i='includes']`, and then on the second `a.includes`, you can do `a[i]` to shave off a byte

Comment: you can also `return 1` instead of `return true`

Comment: @Steffan Thanks for the tips! Only one I'm a bit confused about is replacing (''+n).split with [...''+n]`>. What is that doing?

Comment: @David it uses the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), which spreads the string out into a list.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 84 bytes

```ruby
->n,*r{q=0;1while(r!=r|=[n+=(w=n.digits.join.to_i)*(w<n ?-1:1)])&&q=[]!=[n/100]-r;q}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5PR6uoutDWwNqwPCMzJ1WjSNG2qMY2Ok/bVqPcNk8vJTM9s6RYLys/M0@vJD8@U1NLo9wmT8Fe19DKUDNWU02t0DY6VhGoXt/QwCBWt8i6sPZ/gUJatJGBkVEsF4gFFDc1j/0PAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Javascript](https://www.javascript.com/), <s>94</s> 87 bytes

```
f=(n,s={},x=+[...``+n].reverse().join``,m=x<n?n-x:n+x)=>s[m]?!!(m-11e12+11):f(s[m]=m,s)
```

### How it works!

If the function does get stuck in a forever loop it will max out at the magic number `11e12+11` and this function returns the result minus that number casted to a boolean.

- 7 Bytes thanks to [@Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZHNbsIwEITvPEXggi2c4J91bKMGxIWXQEikNFQg4iBSoUhVnz2N13BAVU@fZj0zayfn8l62h9vp@pX65qPq@2NBPGuL7x/WFbNtlmX7/czvslt1r25tRWh2bk6eTCaU1UX35lc@7RZ@1tFi2W7r3Wo8JnXKuzUXUgmz3mw0XRxJOCpq1tJ@Pk8Et658v1SjQ@Pb5lJll@aTTJ/TKX2ZbwXniiWSS8kSZY1hieNas8TkMEyGU7fL6vJKuqRYJkfSUUpHo2GLb3waOl@3PKf/bNImVAphETlCaggAjUo7RB5hIixi8IT4QFQCA0JCiAsAVOBcgLao8ggTYSOceyA4JVehUwqMS6lCmQSFCixatEGVR5gIG@HsA8GpuAxlSmBcSRnKFEhUYNCi8dEqjzARNsKZB4ITuAhlIDAOAm8Nw0UDAL8gQI5Ore2ff9T/Ag)

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZHBbsIwEETvfEU4EStO8Nrr2EYNfAhCCqWhAhEHkQpFqvrtabyGA6p6eprNzKxjn/f3fX@4na5fue8@mnE8VqnnffX9w4cq2xZFUdeZ3xW35t7c@iZlxbk7@brmbTW8@Y3Ph5XPBlat@22728znaZsDNCAzALY6pmFatbxn43KZgLBu/35pZofO992lKS7dZ7p4ThfsZb4FIRRPpJCSJ8oawxMntOaJKXGaTF/drmj313RIqnVyTAfG2Gw2bfGdz0Pn65bn9J9N2oRKAEsoCVJjAGpS2hHKCBNhCZMnxCeSAgqAxBAHRFLoXIC2pMoIE2EjnHsgOKVQoVMCxaVUoUyiIoWWLNqQKiNMhI1w9oHgVEKGMgUUV1KGMoWSFBqyaPppVUaYCBvhzAPBiQJCGQLFEejUOB00AOkGEUtyam3/vNH4Cw "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online") for 87 bytes